# How do I include a form into my Django file?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a form created in mysite/new_player.html. It accepts 3 fields, user_name, real_name, and site_played that correspond to the Player table in the database.

```
<h1> New Player </h1>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<form action="/stakeme/new/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
User Name: <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name"/><br>
Real Name: <input type="text" name="real_name" id="real_name"/><br>
Site Played: <input type="text" name="site_played" id="site_played"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="New Player" />
</form>
```

I am stuck on how to add this to my mysite/views.py file. I have gone through the polls tutorial, but the only form that is used in the tutorial is a multiple choice "choice" of the "poll" and I can't seem to adapt that to text fields.

```
def new_player(request):
    return render_to_response('stakeme/new_player.html',
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

So as I understand it, I would need to create something like `def add(request): return render_to_response('stakeme/new/'.. etc` and add the POST data in here, but that's where I am lost. I am not sure how to get the data into the database.

I am reading the Django docs, but I feel like I am just compounding something that I do not understand. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I've modified your question to ask more specifically about the problem you're having so it can be answered reasonably. Stack Overflow is not a place to ask for links or lists of tutorials that could help you program or solve problems; we prefer the answers to be posted here. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about that - I figured it would be more acceptable to ask where to learn, than to ask for someone to simply do it for me. I will cut to the point next time. Thanks again.

Comment: You might want to read over the forms overview and then take a look at the model forms documentation.  The django documentation is massive and sometimes hard to navigate, but it's pretty much all there.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/

Comment: I've read that, and I will read it again now. Perhaps it will set in eventually. I feel like this should be simple, but it's just not coming to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to define a new view to process the form data. Also, you are creating your form directly in HTML - it's possible to work this way (see later section of post) but it's better (easier) to use the Django Forms  library.

**Using Django Forms**

The documentation ([v1.3 forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/)) from the start up to and including ''Displaying a form using a template'' explains the basics of using the forms library, so I'll copy & paste liberally from there. I'll also assume that you're familiar with basic python constructs & have Django 1.3 installed. Without further ado, here's my adhoc forms tutorial.

Start a new django project:

```
$ django.admin.py startproject mysite
```

Add a new app:

```
$ ./mysite/manage.py startapp myapp
```

Lets create our contact form (modified from example in Django forms doc). Create a file in side the `myapp/` directory called called `forms.py` and put the following in it:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField()
    sender = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
```

Next, since you mentioned storing data from received contact forms in a database, we'll add a model, Feedback, to track received contact forms. In your `models.py` file, add the following:

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.TextField()
    sender = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Subject:{subject}\nSender:{sender}\n{msg}".format(subject=self.subject,
                                                                sender=self.sender,
                                                                msg=self.message)
```

(You may notice this is very similar to the form we defined earlier; normally in a scenario like this, one would use [Django model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) to create a form directly from a model, but we are building our forms by hand as a learning experience)

We also need to get Django to create the required table in our database for this Feedback model, so at the top of your `settings.py` insert the following useful code:

```
import os
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

And change the [`DATABASES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#databases) setting in `settings.py` to the following to use a [`sqlite`](http://www.sqlite.org/) database:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "sqlite.db").replace('\\', '/'),   # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Finally, change the [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#installed-apps) setting to the following to include our recently created application `myapp` in the list of installed applications for `mysite`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Now run the [`syncdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) command to get Django to create the tables in your sqlite database (which, since it's sqlite, will be created if it doesn't exist yet):

```
$ ./mysite/manage.py syncdb
```

(Django will prompt you to create a superuser as well: you don't have to create a superuser now since we don't need it and you can use [`django-admin.py createsuperuser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser) to create one when you need it, but you can create now now if you like)

Now we need a view to display the contact form, and a view to thank people for submitting it. In your `views.py` file, add the following (modified slightly from Django forms docs):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from myapp.forms import ContactForm
from myapp.models import Feedback

def thanks(request):
    return render_to_response('thanks.html')

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']

            feedback = Feedback(subject=subject, message=message, sender=sender)
            feedback.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('thanks')) # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ContactForm() # An unbound form

    return render_to_response('contact.html', {
        'form': form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now we need to map URLs to views. Open `mysite/urls.py` and make it look like the following

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^thanks/$', 'myapp.views.thanks', name='thanks'),
    url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.contact', name='contact'),
    # url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Now we need some templates to display the contact form & the thankyou page. Create a directory `mysite/templates/`, create a file `contact.html` inside it, and put the following in it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Please fill out the following information and click submit:</p>

        <form action="{% url contact %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also create a `thanks.html` page for the thank you page, and put the following in it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Thanks</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Thank you. Your feedback is important to us</p>

        <p>Please leave some more feedback at the <a href="{% url contact %}">Contact page</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Next, we need to make sure Django can find our templates, so modify the [`TEMPLATE_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#template-dirs) in `mysite/settings.py` setting to the following:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "templates").replace('\\', '/'),
)
```

Now, (finally!), you can run the debug server and test that everything works:

```
$ ./mysite/manage.py runserver 8080
```

Go to http://localhost:8080/ and try to enter some feedback. When you click Submit, it should put your entered details into the database & show the thank you page. You can check the details are entered into the database:

```
$ ./mysite/manage.py shell
```

Into the shell, type:

```
>>> from myapp.models import Feedback
>>> for f in Feedback.objects.all(): print f
```

(note that you need to press enter twice after entering the last line)

You should see the feedback entries you have created.

**Creating forms manually in HTML**

If you insist on doing this, you can access the form's request variables directly in your view using the `request.POST` dictionary, and then instantiating a model of your object manually & calling save (like in the `contact()` view function above).

I would not recommend doing this, because you lose a whole bunch of nice features that Django Forms provides (CSRF protection, validation, etc).

**Other Tutorials**

Since the original form of this question asked for some tutorials: the [official Django wiki](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/) has a [page listing some tutorials](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Tutorials), some of which deal with forms. Be aware that a lot of those tutorials are quite old (mostly from 2007-2009).

Comment: Haha looks like I was a bit slow, but hopefully this helps other people who stumble on this question

Comment: This was great also. Thanks for your effort - it definitely helped me understand the process. Thanks again.

Comment: This is the best answer for a beginner.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to have a good and thorough look at the

Getting started guide https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/

Forms documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

After which you may come up with something along these lines. Untested and quickly scribbled together, likely to be riddled with bugs.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
   user_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   real_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   site_played = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
class PlayerForm(forms.Form):
   user_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
   real_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
   site_played = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
```

views.py

```
def player_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = PlayerForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            user_name = form.cleaned_data['user_name']
            real_name = form.cleaned_data['real_name']
            site_played = form.cleaned_data['site_played']
            player = Player(user_name=user_name, 
                            real_name=real_name, 
                            site_played=site_played)
            player.save()
            # Redirect to a thanks page maybe?

    else:
       form = ContactForm() 

    return render_to_response('contact.html', { 'form': form,})
```

contact.html

```
... lots of fancy html ...
{{ form }}
... more fancy html
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was a great help. I was actually pretty close. My problem lied in having the "forms.py" information in the "models.py" - I did not have a forms.py file.

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this (read about form fields validation yourself):

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Player(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField()
    real_name = models.CharField()
    site_played = models.CharField()
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

MyForm(forms.Form):
   user_name = forms.CharField()
   real_name = forms.CharField()
   site_played = forms.CharField()
```

views.py:

```
from forms import MyForm
from models import Player

def new_player(request):
    #...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            player = Player()
            player.user_name = form.cleaned_data.get('user_name')
            player.real_name = form.cleaned_data.get('real_name')
            player.site_played = form.cleaned_data.get('site_played')
            player.save()
    #...
    return render_to_response('stakeme/new_player.html',
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

UPDATE:
After you get the idea, you might want to have a look at [WTForms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/dev/forms.html) library.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was a great help. I was actually pretty close. My problem lied in having the "forms.py" information in the "models.py" - I did not have a forms.py file.

I will take a look at the WTForms library.

Comment: You shouldn't need to have a forms.py file, that's only convention.