# How to post a array to views.py

Tags: django, arrays, django-templates, django-views

I am using for loop in my template and for different id of each record i am using arrays

```
{% for item in product %}

<div class="register_div">


    <p><label for="id[{{ item.id }}]">{{ item.Name }} </label> <input type="text" name="custom[{{item.id}}]"/></p>

</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Now when in my views i want to save this data to my database.But firstly i checked that whether my array return something or not.So i just try print that as.

```
q = upload_form.data['custom[]']
```

**or**

```
 q = upload_form.data['custom']
```

but it gives me this error

```
"Key 'custom[]' **OR** key custom not found in <QueryDict: {u'custom[2]': [u's'], u'custom[1]': [u'a'], u'price': [u''], u'title': [u''], u'customatt': [u'', u''], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'up4Ipd5L13Efk14MI3ia2FRYScMwMJLz']}>"
```

but if i print this

```
q = upload_form.data['custom[1]']
```

then it display the value of array 1.

so please suggest me a better way to do this how i can display all values inside my array in views.py

Comment: Like I said in my answer to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832693/issues-with-feeding-data-into-database-when-using-for-loop), use the django forms library.

Comment: Ya I am looking at it........but here face the problem about how to display arrays value..because my array takes the values but I am not able to display or to use it so if you suggest me some way how i can do that then its much much better for me.
*and thanks for suggesting me about formsets*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `upload_form.data` is a dictionary, the key 'custom[]' simply doesn't exist. Try something like:

```
custom_values = {}    
for key, value in in upload_form.data.items():
    if key.startswith('custom'):
        custom_values[key]=value
```

The dictionary `custom_values` holds now all your 'custom' form values.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to question, but:

You are not posting an array, but different inputs whose name *looks like* accessing array. e.g. you are posting different input variables named `custom[1]`, `custom[2]` etc. But `custom` is not an array, you will have to access inputs as `custom[1]` etc.

I'm not sure you want this or not!

Comment: But if there are too many records in custom then i have to write that much code......so is there any way so that the no records inside for loop in templates can be accessed in views.py